# How do I call method in current view controller of tabbar controller?

Tags: iphone

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarCtrl; 
}
@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
}
-(void)myMethod;
@end
```

I want to call myMethod in FirstViewControlle.m from MyAppDelegate.m.
I tried this.

```
[self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController myMethod];
```

Compiler says "UIViewController may not respond to myMethod".
How do I call FirstViewController's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast it so the compiler knows the exact type. (you have to be very certain and/or check on runtime if the object actually is that type)

```
[(FirstViewController*) self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController myMethod];
```

Should do it.

And please, compile with "Warnings as errors". This will help you improve your skills, by forcing you to "solve" all warnings. And I think you have a lot to learn still ;-)

Comment: such a casting can cause a run-tima crash in case self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController is not of kind FirstViewController. You can ask whether it respondsToSelector(myMethod:) and then perform your selector on the main thread

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Actually, I have to call method in main thread from second thread. [(FirstViewController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:(NSNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:number] waitUntilDone:YES]; has no comiler warning. But it does not work. Is above correct?

Comment: Doing a "performSelector" obscures simple (compile-time) type checks though. Also, the question didn't mention threading so your advice is a bit over the top. A simple "performSelector" is enough, no need for "performSelectorOnMainThread"

Comment: To the original question: if you choose to do "performSelector", you can leave out the casting. The compiler will not check selectors passed as arguments. It probably crashes because self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController is not an instance of FirstViewController - just check it in the debugger. Store the value of self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController in a temporary variable and do a "print description to console" on that variable.

Comment: Reading your code in the comment: the cast for [NSNumber numberWithInt:] is superfluous, it already has the correct type. Are you sure your selector is okay? Your original sample did not contain a ":" at the end.

Comment: Debugger does not step into method in another thread. So, I thought it did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are calling a method on UIViewController Obj-C can't assure that the method exists.
You could just check if the methods exsist:

```
if([self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController repondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
  [self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
}
```

This ways allows you to create the myMethod on more then just FirstViewController

Comment: Also fine, but see my comment above about compile-time warnings. The choice (casting versus run-time checking) depends on the design. If your design guarantees self.tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController is an instance of a certain class, use the cast (it gets you some static typechecks). Perhaps add an assertion in there for safety. Conversely, if you expect multiple types, do the run-time check suggested here and by Nava Carmon

Comment: The run time check is more stable in the case where to user changes to ordering of the tabs. I do agree that cast will give nice static typecheck.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends. If you have a priori knowledge of the object type (or more commonly: you think that you have ;-) I prefer the cast.